# Forbidden you don't have permission to access /~username/Sites from this server

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

Just back from six months away with work, wireframe in hand, ready to try my hand at programming again, only to be met with 'Forbidden you don't have permission to access localhost/~username/Sites from this server' when trying to open a textwrangler .php file in safari.

It worked a few weeks before I left, but now even those projects refuse to open. I've spent my first weekend off googling like a mad 'un, trying all the solutions without success. 10 hours over two days and nothing.

So I'm hoping those with more knowledge than I can think of what could have gone belly up. Localhost by itself returns the 'It Works!' message. I have run Apache configtest; it stated something  but I've resolved that. Now it returns syntax OK. The httpd file has allow where it should be. And I've checked that I'm a user in the users list and that there is a config file with the same name. Added localhost after ServerName in the httpd file. Restarted Apache but that also failed.

Nothing has been updated or changed in respect to OS or browser. I installed the arduino software at Christmas, I can't see that don't anything but it may mean something to you. I don't get how it can now not work when nothing has changed? I'm running Mavericks and it's Apache 2.2. I am stumped, and I'm hoping someone may have a clue. The guys at Apple's store said they couldn't help because it's not their software.

If you could answer in baby steps it would be greatly appreciated as I thought I knew computers until I started opening the terminal and doing all this.

Thank you very much for your time and advice, 
Keep well

EDIT: console log displays - client denied by server configuration: /Users/myUserName/Sites

Comment: First, check the apache error log -- it often has more detailed info about the cause of the error. Second, check the file permissions (on the php file, *and* your Sites folder, and your home folder) to make sure that the _www user has read access (note that _www will usually be in the "other" / "everyone" access category). Third, are you using a URL that specifies the folder, or the .php file specifically? If the folder, make sure you have the default index filename set correctly and/or that folder listing is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. console log displays - client denied by server configuration: /Users/myUserName/Sites. And I am the only user on the laptop, there are no other accounts.